# como incrementar letras no php?

Tags: php, auto-incremento, caracteres

Eu preciso fazer uma programa no php que incremente uma letra no nome recebido ex:

se o usuário digitar letra B preciso transforma-la em uma adiante ou seja C.

Comment: você pode criar um vetor com todas as letras do alfabeto, quando o usuário digitar a letra, encontrar a letra no vetor e pegar o próximo índice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No php só é possível usar o operador de incremento (`++`) em letras (o de decremento `--` não se aplica) pois ele incrementa o código ASCII do caracter os intervalos válidos são A-Z 65-90, a-z 97-122

Pode gerar o alfabeto dessa forma:

```
$alfabeto = range('A', 'Z');
print_r($alfabeto); 

$letra = 'B';
echo ++$letra; //imprime C
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode converter o caractere para ASCII, incrementar +1 e voltar a convertê-lo para caractere:

```
echo ord("B"); //retorna 66
echo chr(ord("B")+1); //retorna "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

Duma maneira não ortodoxa e [`XGH`](http://sou.gohorseprocess.com.br/extreme-go-horse-(xgh)/):

```
$letra = 'C';
$alfabeto = range('A', 'Z');

$proxima = $alfabeto[array_search($letra, $alfabeto) +1]; 

var_dump($proxima); // string(1) "D"
```

Comment: Seria interessante notar que ao fazer o resto da divisão pelo tamanho da lista, `$alfabeto[(array_search($letra, $alfabeto)+1) % count($alfabeto)]`, a letra `Z` é convertida em `A`, supondo que este é o comportamento desejado (não ficou claro na pergunta).

Comment: Sim sim, @AndersonCarlosWoss. Como realmente não está claro como é desejado o resultado caso seja a letra `Z`, não mencionei.